Linux Mint: Why can't Flutter run adb and why does vscode keep saying flutter daemon has terminated
I'm having trouble getting flutter working on my new linux mint install. I have two problems:
First problem:
flutter doctor returns
[☠] Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message
      below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at
      https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ Error: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and
      ANDROID_HOME environment variable:

What's weird about this is that in the same terminal i CAN run adb:
me:~$ adb
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 35.0.1-11580240
Installed as /home/yannick/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
Running on Linux 5.15.0-116-generic (x86_64)

I've checked numerous online solutions, but it seems my paths are all set correctly and i don't know what could cause this?
My bashrc paths:
export FLUTTER_HOME="/usr/bin/flutter"
export PATH="$PATH:$FLUTTER_HOME/bin"
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/yannick/Android/Sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"

Second problem:
In VSCode, it keeps showing me this error: "The Flutter Daemon has terminated.", with an option to reload. However when i reload it still doesn't work. i've already tried restart vscode and restarting my laptop. Both didn't help.
Can these issues be related? What can i do?
I tried reinstalling platform-tools, i tried restarting my laptop, i tried different path variables and restarting all terminals. I verified my installations, can echo my paths, however
yannick@KRULBROODJE:~$ android Command 'android' not found, did you mean: command 'androdd' from deb androguard (3.4.0~a1-1) Try: sudo apt install <deb name> 
yannick@KRULBROODJE:~$ android --version Command 'android' not found, did you mean: command 'androdd' from deb androguard (3.4.0~a1-1) Try: sudo apt install <deb name> 
